# How to process the form read by fastapi middleware

Tags: fastapi

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request, UploadFile, Form, File
from starlette.datastructures import UploadFile as StarletteUploadFile
from functools import wraps

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware("http")
async def middleware_log(request: Request, call_next):
    content_type = request.headers.get("Content-Type")
    if content_type and "multipart/form-data" in content_type:
        form = await request.form()
        print(form.values())
        log_data = {
            "files": [
                {
                    "filename": file.filename, 
                    "file_size": str(round(file.size / 1024, 2)) + 'KB', 
                    "content_type": file.content_type
                } for file in form.values() if isinstance(file, StarletteUploadFile)
            ],
            "form_fields": {k: v for k, v in form.items() if not isinstance(v, StarletteUploadFile)}
        }
        print(log_data)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

I want to take a log for the route when request in my route, so add middleware, but when I take form message, the next route or middleware can't process the file or form data, hope can give some suggestions, thanks!

I try to set form value in to request._form, but it's wrong

Comment: You should be able to follow the same recipe as the GZipRequest middleware shown in FastAPIs documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/custom-request-and-route/#handling-custom-request-body-encodings - i.e. you create a class that acts as the body for the next step in the chain and set that as the body.

Comment: Are there alternative methods to address this issue? For instance, retrieving the receive attribute from the Request object, then setting it back into the Request object afterwards.